# How to find brightest rectangle of certain size in integral image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Is there anything faster than sliding window? I tried sort of binary search with overlapping rectangles - it kinda works but sometimes cuts off part of the blob (expected, right) - see the video in http://juick.com/lurker/2142051

Answer (score 1):

Binary search makes no sense, because it is an algorithm for searching for specific values in a *sorted* structure.

Unless you have some apriori knowledge about the image, you need to check all possible locations, which is the sliding window method you suggested.

Comment: well yes, you could argue that lots of dark grey pixels could give larger sum that pitch black background with small white blob, but this does not actually happen, probably because both black and dark grey are equally distributed in the difference image.

Comment: Think of the analog in one dimension.  You have an unsorted list of numbers and want to find the largest number in the last.  You cannot give a sure answer without checking all numbers in the list

Comment: Yes and no. If you have, say, 100 numbers, 99 of which are noise in range 0..1, and 1 is signal that you need to find an index of, and you have sums of numbers 1..50 and 51..100, then, in order for sums to guarantee that the signal is in either range, you only need the signal to be something over 50 - no need for the list to be sorted. Then, if it is below 50, it is, indeed, the question of probability.

Comment: P.S. now that I was thinking about this list example for whole 15 minutes, I think maybe I could try to find the brightest pixel in every row when I build the integral image, and see if that data is somehow useful.

Answer (score 0):

Chris is correct, unless you can say something about the statistics of the surrounding regions, e.g., "certain arrangements of pixels around the spot I'm looking for are unlikely".  Note, this is different from saying "will never happen", and any algorithm based on statistical approaches will have an associated probability of (wrong box found).

If you think the statistics of the larger regions around your desired location might be informative, you might be able to do some block-processing on larger blocks before doing the fine-level sliding window.  For example, if you can say with high probability that a certain 64 x 64 region *doesn't* contain the max, then, you can throw out a lot of [64 x 64] pixel regions, with 32 pixel overlap using (maybe) only a few features.

You can train something like AdaBoost to do this.  See the classic Viola-Jones work which does this for face-detection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework

If you absolutely need the maxima location, then like Chris said, you need to search everywhere.

Comment: see my 2nd comment to Chris, but yes - in my case the image is (or rather should be) mostly near-black (because it is the difference between supposedly aligned frame and running average), and only moving objects should ideally leave white blobs. my task is to find these blobs. currently it does not do good job (as you see in video) but it costs only 9 sum calculations versus potentially hundreds or thousands in the case of sliding window.